# Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. but ONLY ME

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For one specific FB user account, certain URLs on our site cannot be shared to FB (title, image etc. doesn't show up), plus when attempting to debug the same URL this FB user gets:

"Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Turns out that this error only happens when logged into the FB account that created the App for the site. It has been confirmed that several other FB users are able to share and debug the same URL just fine.

This happens irrespective of geo-location (tried in U.S., Ecuador and Canada), browser (tried with FF, IE, Opera, Chrome), OS (tried in Windows and MAC), etc.

Here is an example URL where this is happening.
http://news.therawfoodworld.com/3-men-special-ladies/

On average, out of about 10 posts published, 7 will work as expected, 3 won't.

Any ideas?

Update: I deleted the app associated with the site, still not working.
Update: I edited the "slug" for the URL and it works.. so it's not an issue with the OG tags... I added "-2" to the URL to create:
http://news.therawfoodworld.com/3-men-special-ladies-2/

But still.. what's the deal?